# Firebase 100 Million nodes in read operation limit

Tags: firebase

The firebase docs say that nodes in read operation limited to 100 million. What nodes is this limitation referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referring to this page: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/understanding-data.html

The page contains a table called "Limitations and Restrictions"

Depth of child nodes    32
Length of a key     768 bytes   UTF-8 encoded, cannot contain . $ [ ] / or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127
Size of one child value     10mb    UTF-8 encoded
Write from SDK  16mb    UTF-8 encoded
Write from REST     256mb
**Nodes in a read operation     100 million**

This refers to the nodes (elements) in the JSON structures you are reading.

I.e. the following JSON object: `{"id": 1, "name": "John Doe"}`
contains two nodes, `id` and `name`. The object itself is the parent node, making a total of 3.

The following JSON array:

`[ {"id": 1, "name": "John Doe"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Jane Doe"}]`

Contains 2x3 nodes plus the array = 7 nodes.

Comment: Yes thats the page I was referring to. So if a read operation results in more than 100 million such nodes, you'll have to page the results right ?

Comment: Exactly. I guess Firebase chose to count the number of JSON nodes (instead of the record count, or JSON object count) so you cannot go around the limit by combining multiple objects in JSON arrays. Your queries must be limited to return <=100M nodes so you need to look at filters and/or sharding.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer How long for a chlid node Max?. For example, I have /orders/{orderObj}.    So how many {orderObj} i can keep [use push()]  ?

Comment: When I was going through the API, the limit was only on the total amount of nodes in the query. So the answer depends on the amount of nodes in one orderObj. That would be one for the orderObj itself + 1 for every column in it.