# Firebase - Maximum number of nodes that can be created in firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a community based chat app using firebase. I wanted to know what can be the maximum number of nodes that can be created in firebase database.

As of now the users for the app is less so the number of nodes isn't a concern. But I just made a calculation for the worst case where there are 5000 users chatting with 5000 other users. In that case the number of nodes would be 2,50,00,000.

I read through the limitations([Firebase Database limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits)) of firebase database documentation and I couldn't find any information on the limit of number of nodes.

Comment: I don't think there is a numerical cap, It's capped at the maximum size (in GB) that you can store according to your subscription

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You couldn't find any information on the limit of the number of nodes because it doesn't exist. There is no limitation regarding the number of nodes. I assure you that at the moment, there are many databases that are larger than you say and are working perfectly fine.

The limitations that exist can be read [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

Comment: There is actually a better/more detailed page for database limits nowadays: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits. But there is indeed no defined limit on the number of nodes. There probably is a technical limit somewhere, but I don't think anyone has found it yet.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen!

Answer (score 1):

There is a somewhat unspoken limit of **100 million nodes** that you can have under any given parent in the Firebase Realtime Database - [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199656/firebase-100-million-nodes-in-read-operation-limit).

This is due to the fact that the database is stored in 'hot' memory when being used, so more than 100 million nodes would mean too great an amount of memory is being used for your database.

However, I wouldn't worry about this for the mean time.  If your database begins to grow to this point, you should contact Firebase Support and they will help you shard your data across multiple databases.